# Implementation code for GetDateFormat Win32 function

Tags: c, datetime, winapi, ubuntu, date

I am porting some legacy code from windows to Linux (Ubuntu Karmic to be precise).

I have come across a Win32 function GetDateFormat().

The statements I need to port over are called like this:

```
GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, &datetime, "MMMM", 'January', 31);

OR

GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, &datetime, "MMMM", 'May', 30);
```

Where datetime is a SYSTEMTIME struct.

Does anyone know where I can get the code for the function - or failing that, tips on how to "roll my own" equivalent function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux equivalent (actually, plain ANSI C) to a call to `GetDateFormat` like this:

```
GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, &datetime, "MMMM", date_str, len);
```

is:

```
char *old_lc_time;

/* Set LC_TIME locale to user default */
old_lc_time = setlocale(LC_TIME, NULL);
setlocale(LC_TIME, "");

strftime(date_str, len, "%B", &datetime);

/* Set LC_TIME locale back */
setlocale(LC_TIME, old_lc_time);
```

(where `datetime` is now a `struct tm` rather than a `SYSTEMTIME`)

You may not need to worry about setting the locale each time and setting it back - if you are happy for *all* of your date/time formatting to be done in the user default locale (which is usual), then you can just call `setlocale(LC_TIME, "");` once at program startup and be done with it.

Note however that the values your code is passing to `GetDateFormat` in the `lpDateStr` and `cchDate` parameters (second-last and last respectively) do *not* make sense.  `'January'` is a character constant, when it should be a pointer to a buffer where `GetDateFormat` will place its result.

Answer (score 1):

The Win32 [GetDateFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318086(VS.85).aspx) function should be equivalent to the [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) function in the time.h header.